# why numpy variance of a matrix or vector gives a scalar

Tags: numpy, covariance, variance

**Updated**: use `np.cov` instead, if you would like to get a matrix.

Given a vector `vec= np.array([1,2,3,4])`, why `np.var(vec)` return me a scalar instead of [variance-covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) in mathematics [definiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99560/generalization-of-variance-to-random-vectors)?

This holds even after I force the vector to be column vector, `vec_column = vec[:, np.newaxis]`, `np.var(vec_columb)` still gives a scalar instead of the usual definiation.

Also, given a matrix `a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])` or `a = np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')`, why `np.var(a)` return me a scaler.

Comment: Trying to take the variance-covariance matrix of `array([1, 2, 3, 4])` doesn't make any sense. You need multiple observations of multiple variables to take a variance-covariance matrix; this looks like either 4 observations of one variable, or a single observation in 4 variables.

Comment: Hi, @user2357112, thanks for pointing out this! If `vec = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5,6,7,8]])` then `np.cov(vec)` should be the correlation between 4 variables given two observations?

Comment: That'd be a covariance matrix for 4 observations of 2 variables.

Comment: Hi @user2357112, sorry for this silly question, how can I distinguish two cases? Does this is a requirement by design?

Comment: Hi @user2357112, btw, I just skimmed [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html), the bottom example shows `np.cov([-2.1, -1,  4.3])`.

Comment: It's in the docs. Also, the last example does show `np.cov([-2.1, -1, 4.3])`, but it's also not returning any sort of matrix; it's giving a variance estimate for one variable (with ddof=1, which is why it differs from the `np.var` output).

Comment: I see, it is equal to `np.var`. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @user2357112 I guess I still not get your point: suppose I have a variable of `c` shape [2,3], then let's have three observations `c0, c1, c2= np.random.normal(0, 1, [2,3]) `, then how can I get the covariance/variance of variable given `c0, c1, c2`? I have tried `np.cov(np.array[c0, c1, c2])` but with error `ValueError: m has more than 2 dimensions`.

Comment: If I try `np.cov(c0, c1, c2)`, then `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: @ytutow: Please do not edit the solution to your problem into your question! On Stack Overflow solutions go to the answers section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.cov()` for the covariance matrix. See the docs [var](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.var.html) and [cov](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html).

Comment: Trying to take `np.cov(vec)` just gives you `array(1.6666666666666665)`, though. Trying to take the covariance matrix of this input just doesn't make sense.